# Paypal integration in c# .net

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, paypal, c#-3.0, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm working on c#.net project, in that i need to add vantiv payment process to my project and i'd like to use PayPal SDK.
Can anyone please tell me how to integrate PayPal's SDK for free.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

There's a few good ones. I always prefer PayPal's github docs - [Payapal .NET  Github Wiki](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki)

First you need to [Sign-Up](https://www.paypal.com/signup/account) to a PayPal developer's account and then update your web.config with the given key using the following code (taken from the link above):

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
      <add name="clientId" value="__CLIENT_ID__" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="__CLIENT_SECRET__" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```

Good luck my friend.